# Java help! Trying to figure out how the for loop works

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create new instance of random class
    Random rand = new Random();
    // set variable num to be a random number between 0 and 10
    int user = rand.nextInt(10);
    // set output equal to the result of our function
    int password = check_password(user);
    // print result
    System.out.println(password);

}

// returns the factorial of the given input- by what number i is 
// i can be less than or equal to 10
    public static int check_password(int user) {
    int log = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= user; i++) {
        log = log * i;
    }
    return log;
    }
```

I am confused on how the answer can be higher than 10, i don't understand how it can print answers when you run the code in eclipse: 
40320
120
6
5040
24
2
1
362880

I am supposed to figure out what the code does and write it in the code in comments

Comment: Why is a method called `check_password` calculating a factorial?

Comment: I am not sure why the person who wrote the code did that, the code was obfuscated and i got rid of the necessary methods that were in the code

Comment: When you step through the code in a debugger, line by line as it executes, and observe the runtime behavior... Which specific operation produces an unexpected result?  It's not clear to me what you *expect* this code to be doing.  But it can most certainly produce numbers greater than 10.

Comment: i have to figure out what the code does and explain it in the code

Comment: Do you understand what "[factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)" means? If not, now is a good time to learn (e.g. click the link). If you do, why are you confused that factorial of a number as high as 9 can be more than 10? I mean, e.g. `factorial(4)` is **24**,

Comment: @Emilie: *"i have to figure out what the code does"* - That's a great reason to use a debugger.  You can *observe* what the code does.  Aside from that, this program is small enough to just use pencil and paper.  Choose any random value for `user` (since it's random from 1-10) and walk through the code.  What result were you expecting for your value?  What result did the program return for your value?  Is it different?  Why were you expecting something different?  Where did it first begin to differ?

Answer (score 0):

Your "check_password" method is actually calculating the factorial of the number. Example if number is generated to be 5, your method will return 120. So the output could be well above 10 as factorial of 10 is 3628800

Comment: That information is already in the question, in the comment above the method.  OP clearly doesn't understand what a factorial is, so this answer won't help her much.

Comment: the for loop is that confused me, visualizing it is my head. that makes more sense thank you

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Sorry, I missed reading the comment on the method. She asked how could the output be higher than 10, I explained that part.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will loop however many times the random int user was set to. Each time it loops, it will perform `log * i`. I being which iteration of the loop it's on.  So if user was randomly set to 5, it will loop 5 times. The first loop will perform `1 * 1`, which will set log to 1. The next loop will perform `1 * 2`, setting the log to 2. The third loop will perform `2 * 3`, setting the log to 6, and so on. With int user randomly set to 5, the final log will be 120.  You are returning the final value of log, and setting it equal to your password, then printing out the password. This is why the value you're printing is greater than 10.

Comment: sorry just a typo